# Can you use a string for record access in elm?

Tags: elm

If I have a string that looks like the name of a field in a record, can I use it to get the data somehow? Something like :

```
."name".toKey bill 
bill.(asSymbol "name")
```

-

```
song =
  { title = "foot", artist = "barf", number = "13" }

fieldsILike : List String
fieldsILike =
  [ "title", "artist" ]


val song key =
  .key song

foo = List.map (val song) fieldsILike --> should be ["foot", "barf"]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not the way you want it but you can have a function that pattern matches on a string to access a part of a record. You need to be explicit about what it should do in case you give it something invalid.

```
import Html exposing (..) 

type alias Song = { artist : String, number : String, title : String }

song : Song
song =
  { title = "foot", artist = "barf", number = "13" }

fieldsILike : List String
fieldsILike =
  [ "title", "artist" ]


k2acc : String -> (Song -> String)
k2acc key = 
  case key of 
  "title" ->  .title
  "artist" -> .artist
  "number" -> .number
  _ ->  always ""

val : Song -> String -> String
val = flip k2acc 
-- `flip` was removed in elm 0.19, so you'll need to 
-- do something like the following going forward: 
-- val song field = (k2acc field) song   

foo = List.map (val song) fieldsILike

main = text <| toString foo
```

Answer (score 5):

No, but you could use a [Dict](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/3.0.0/Dict)

```
import Dict exposing (get ,fromList)

song = fromList [ ("title", "foot"), ("artist", "barf") ]

get "title" song -- Just "foot"
get "artist" song -- Just "barf"
get "test" song  -- Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this broblem by adding attribute's name and explicit type declaration in `AttrValue` type:

```
type alias TypedRecord =
    List Attr

type alias Attr =
    ( String, AttrValue )


type AttrValue
    = String String
    | Int Int
    | Record (List Attr)
```

So now i can retrieve attributes by `"key"` (even `"key.key"` for nested) from my `TypedRecord` type:

```
getAttrByKey : String -> TypedRecord -> Maybe Attr
getAttrByKey searchKey item =
    -- imitation of searching for attributes likewise in JS Record
    let
        checkAttrKey =
            \k attr ->
                first attr == k
    in
    case String.split "." searchKey of
        [ key ] ->
            List.head <| List.filter (checkAttrKey key) item

        key :: rest ->
            case List.head <| List.filter (checkAttrKey key) item of
                Just attr ->
                    case attr of
                        ( _, Record subAttr ) ->
                            getAttrByKey (String.join "." rest) subAttr

                        ( _, _ ) ->
                            Nothing

                Nothing ->
                    Nothing

        [] ->
            Nothing
```

And conver it to `String` by checking `Attr` type and calling respected Elm `String` module function:

```
attrToString : Maybe Attr -> String
attrToString is_attr =
    case is_attr of
        Nothing ->
            ""

        Just attr ->
            case second attr of
                String value ->
                    value

                Int value ->
                    String.fromInt value

                Record attrs ->
                    List.map (\a -> Just a) attrs
                        |> List.map (\a -> attrToString a)
                        |> String.join " "
```

These examples for `String` `Int` and `Record` Elm types, but it is also can be extended fo `Float` `Bool` and `Array`.
You can check `src/lib/TypedRecord.elm` file for another functions and even Json Decoder in my [example app repository](https://github.com/Yuri2b/elm_table)